# Create a file with special character with ftplib python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftplib

I am trying to create a script which read all the '.csv' files in a ftp directory and create files with same name in that directory itself. The new files create would be exactly the same but with extension '.done'.

Now iam troubling here with the special character. Its not allowing me to create file name with special character. Please help me what should we do here?
Here is a snippet of my code

```
import ftplib
from  datetime import date
import glob, os


ftp = ftplib.FTP("host.com")
ftp.login("hostlogin", "yourpwd")
ftp.cwd('/test')

filenames = ftp.nlst('*.csv')

print (filenames)

for file in filenames:
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % file+'.done', f)
        f.close()

ftp.quit()
```

Iam getting this error though:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'blabla_2020-02-19_03:56:10.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the error, is not from invalid character, but rather from that you are trying to open file locally which is on ftp.

If you want to just rename file use `ftp.rename(fromname, toname)` command:

```
for file in filenames:
    ftp.rename(file, f"{file}.done")
```

If you want to make copy through ftp you should first retrive file locally and then upload it with different name:

```
for file in filenames:
    with open(file, "wb") as f:
        ftp.retrbinary(f"RETR {file}", lambda data: f.write(data))

    with open(file, "rb") as f:
        ftp.storbinary(f"STOR {file}.done", f)
```